# ACF: replace comma with another sign

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF.

I am using this function to display numbers in number fields in this way 1,000.00

```
// Return ACF Number Fields Formatted with Commas on the Frontend
add_filter('acf/format_value/type=number', 'acf_number_comma_decimal', 20, 3);

// Without Decimal
function acf_number_comma($value, $post_id, $field) {
$value = number_format(floatval($value));
return $value;
}
// With Decimal
function acf_number_comma_decimal($value, $post_id, $field) {
$value = number_format(floatval($value), 2);
return $value;
}
```

I would like to replace the ” , ” with this ” ‘ ” so the value will be displayed in this way: 1’000.00.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

`number_format` function in PHP takes 4 arguments:

- `num`
- `decimals`
- `decimal_separator`
- `thousands_separator`

You can specify your favourite separators as string, like this:

```
// With Decimal
function acf_number_comma_decimal($value, $post_id, $field) {
  $value = number_format(floatval($value), 2, ".", "'");
  return $value;
}
```

From the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php